# how to change the values of a rows if the values ​are the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import random
import pandas as pd
turn = []
turn_list_input = []   
employee_list_input = []   
turn_list_input = [item for item in input("Orari: ").split()]
employee_list_input = [item for item in input("Personale: ").split()]
while len(employee_list_input)>0:
    x = random.choice(employee_list_input)
    turn.append(x)
    new_new_list =random.sample(turn_list_input, 5)
    turn += new_new_list
    employee_list_input.remove(x)
test = {}
for i in turn:
    if i.isalpha():
          items = test[i] = []
    elif test:
          items.append(i)
df = pd.DataFrame(test, index=['Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Gio', 'Ven'])
print(df)
```

I am a beginner (stepped into programming a few days ago during covid lockdown lol) and self-taught, i'm trying to improve myself every day but... i'm stuck on this problem! (it's a project i'm doing for hobby)

Is there a way to tell the program to read the lines and change the equal values ​​to another random value?
let me explain!

that's my result:

```
       l    g   r   t   h   e   y    a    j    k    d   u   q    f   s
Lun   10   14  10  11  10  13  12   13  14R   10   13  14   9    9  11
Mar    9   12  12  10  14  10   9   14   13    7    8  12   8   14  13
Mer   14  14R  13  12  11   9   7    8   12  14R  14R   8  14   11  12
Gio  14R    9  11  13   8   7  11  14R   14   14   10  10  13   10  10
Ven   12    7  14   8   9  12   8    9    7    9    9   7   7  14R   8
```

each row should have only one "7", one "14" and one "14R".

each column cannot have "7" or "8" or "9" after "14" or "14R"

thanks in advance for any reply! (and sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to precisely pinpoint where do you want to get your replacement values from, but this code will allow you to get all the places you have to replace:

```
row_condition = df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, axis=1)

col_condition = df.apply(lambda x: np.logical_and(x.isin(['14','14R']).shift(1, fill_value=False), x.isin(['7','8', '9'])))

to_replace = np.logical_or(row_condition, col_condition)
```

you can then replace them with:

```
df.where(~to_replace, some_unique_values)
```